# How do I get my Windows 7 PC to recognize Kindle 3G (latest gen)?

Tags: windows-7, usb, kindle

I have a Windows 7 Home Premium Dell laptop and a new Kindle 3G+WiFi. I have been trying to get my laptop to recognize this and upgrade the firmware. All I am able to do it connect to the Kindle store directly from my device and buy/read books.

I have tried all the possible remedies I could think of. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.